# LISP- Delete vowels from a string

Tags: string, lisp, common-lisp

I want to write a function that deletes all vowels from a string. I thought of defining a function that detects the vowels, something similar to symbolp, zerop and so on and if it is a vowel, delete it. How can I do this? I would appreciate any input on this. Thanks

```
(defun deletevowels (string)
(go through the list
   (if vowel-p deletevowels )
)
)
```

Nevertheless, I have the problem that deletes a vowel if it's the last, how can I modify this to meet what I want to do, to delete all vowels in a string? In the code below there's this function I was mentioning, vowel-p one.

```
(defun strip-vowel (word)
  "Strip off a trailing vowel from a string."
  (let* ((str (string word))
         (end (- (length str) 1)))
    (if (vowel-p (char str end))
        (subseq str 0 end)
        str)))

(defun vowel-p (char) (find char "aeiou" :test #'char-equal))
```

Moreover, is it easier if I would use the function below to turn the string into a list and then loop in the list instead of the string to look for the vowel and remove it?

```
(defun string-to-list (string)
  (loop for char across string collect char))
```

Comment: just use `REMOVE-IF`.

Comment: So what you're saying is to loop through the string and remove-if vowelp?

Comment: `(defun delete_vowels (word)
          (let (str (string word))
               (end (- (length str) 1))
          )
        (remove-if #'vowel-p str end)
    )

(defun vowel-p (char) (find char "aeiou" :test #'char-equal))`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CL-USER 27 > (defun vowel-p (char)
               (find char "aeiou" :test #'char-equal))
VOWEL-P

CL-USER 28 > (remove-if #'vowel-p "abcdef")
"bcdf"
```

See: Common Lisp Hyperspec, [REMOVE-IF](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_rm.htm#remove-if).

```
CL-USER 29 > (defun deletevowels (string)
               (remove-if #'vowel-p string))
DELETEVOWELS

CL-USER 30 > (deletevowels "spectacular")
"spctclr"
```

Comment: And if I were to put the 'remove-if' in a function that would have a name defined by me, how would that look like? So I would just call (deletevowels "spectacular") and it would give me "spctclr".